# how can a WCF Java clients Send GZIP Compressed Requests to service?

Tags: java, xml, wcf, gzip, wcf-interoperability

i have application with WCF Service which Receives a big input string parameters size , and all service clients are java ,i had found a built in compression mechanism using custom binding element configured as follow :

```
 <bindings>
            <customBinding>
              <binding name="name">
                <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/>
                <httpTransport />
              </binding>
            </customBinding>
  </bindings>
```

but i understood this use binary message encoding which is not operable .

My Question :

can i use the built in binding element compression to receive compressed message from java client , if not , what is the possible way for the java clients send a compressed message?

Comment: You can try running the wsdl through Metro and see what it comes up with, I'm not sure what you'll find.  I think the compression was added in .Net 4.5, which isn't all that old.  https://metro.java.net/